# Produce the sum of products over two lists with python?

Tags: python, sympy

Using `sympy` I have two lists:

```
terms = [1, x, x*(x-1)]
coefficients = [-1,8.1,7]
```

I need to get the output:

```
-1+8.1*x+7*x(x-1)
```

I tried:

```
print (sum(a,x__i) for a, x__i in izip(terminos,coeficientes))
```

But I actually got a `generator`, I tried such based on a working code:

```
def lag_l(xx, j):
    x = Symbol("x")
    parts = ((x - x_i) / (xx[j] - x_i) for i, x_i in enumerate(xx) if i != j)
    return prod(parts)

def lag_L(xx, yy):
    return sum(y*lag_l(xx, j) for j, y in enumerate(yy))
```

How can I complete this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [159]: import sympy as sy

In [160]: from sympy.abc import x

In [161]: terms = [1, x, x*(x-1)]

In [162]: coefficients = [-1,8.1,7]

In [163]: sum(t*c for t, c in zip(terms, coefficients))
Out[163]: 7*x*(x - 1) + 8.1*x - 1
```

---

Interestingly, `sum(term*coef for term, coef in zip(terms, coefficients))` is a bit faster than `sum(coef * term for coef, term in zip(coefficients, terms))`:

```
In [182]: %timeit sum(term * coef for term, coef in zip(terms, coefficients))
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.1 µs per loop

In [183]: %timeit sum(coef * term for coef, term in zip(coefficients, terms))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.7 µs per loop
```

The reason for this is because `coef * term` calls `coef.__mul__(term)` which then has to call `term.__rmul__(coef)` since ints do not know how to multiply with `sympy` Symbols. That extra function call makes `coef * term` slower than `term * coef`. (`term * coef` calls `term.__mul__(coef)` directly.)

Here are some more microbenchmarks:

```
In [178]: %timeit sum(IT.imap(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38 µs per loop

In [186]: %timeit sum(IT.imap(op.mul, terms, coefficients))
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.8 µs per loop

In [179]: %timeit sum(map(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.5 µs per loop

In [188]: %timeit sum(map(op.mul, terms, coefficients))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.3 µs per loop
```

Notice that the order of the `terms` and `coefficients` matters, but otherwise there is little time difference between these variants. For larger input, they also perform about the same:

```
In [203]: terms = [1, x, x*(x-1)] * 100000

In [204]: coefficients = [-1,8.1,7] * 100000

In [205]: %timeit sum(IT.imap(op.mul, terms, coefficients))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.63 s per loop

In [206]: %timeit sum(term * coef for term, coef in zip(terms, coefficients))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.63 s per loop

In [207]: %timeit sum(map(op.mul, terms, coefficients))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.48 s per loop
```

Also be aware that if you do not know (through profiling) that this operation is a critical bottleneck in your code, worrying about these slight differences is a waste of your time, since the time it takes to pre-optimize this stuff is far greater than the amount of time you save whilst the code is running. As they say, [preoptimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). I'm probably already guilty of that.

---

In Python2,

```
sum(IT.imap(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
```

uses the least memory.

In Python3, `zip` and `map` returns iterators, so

```
sum(t*c for t, c in zip(terms, coefficients))    
sum(map(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
```

would also be memory-efficient.

Comment: I doubt the `term*coef` vs `coef*term` pattern generalizes.

Comment: @asmeurer: Can you give an example?

Comment: The reason it's faster is that `coef*term` first calls `coeff.__mul__(term)`, which returns `NotImplemented`, so it falls back to `term.__rmul__(coeff)`, whereas `term*coef` calls `term.__mul__(coef)`, which works. But this is *extremely* over optimizing. And if `coeff` came from another SymPy operation (so that it were a SymPy type), it would not apply. I don't think it deserves mentioning in this answer; it only serves to confuse. If you want to optimize something, look at the effect of your `*=` (I think here there is no effect, but in general it is O(n^2) when it could be O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple generator expression:

```
sum(coef * term for coef, term in zip(coefficients, terms))
```

Alternatively, instead of using `zip` you want to use something similar to `zip_with`:

```
def zip_with(operation, *iterables):
    for elements in zip(*iterables):
        yield operation(*elements)
```

And use it as:

```
import operator as op

sum(zip_with(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
```

As unutbu mentioned python already provide such a function in [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) under python2 and the built'-in's [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) in python3, so you can avoid re-writing it and use either:

```
sum(itertools.imap(op.mul, coefficients, terms))
```

or

```
sum(map(op.mul, coefficients, terms) #python3
```

python 2 `map` works slightly differently when you pass more than one sequence and the length differ.

Comment: `sum(itertools.imap(op.mul, coefficients, terms))` also works.

Comment: Which of all options in two current answers might me more memory/cpu optimal?

Comment: @unutbu Yeah. somehow I've always forget about multi-iterable `map`. I'm too used to Haskell's `zipWith`.

Comment: Is there any way to give both of you accepted answer? :p